# Can we ask psychological and social issues related to music on this site?

Tags: discussion

There is a question in my mind, obsessing me, which is not directly about instruments, or composition, or harmony, etc. and that is:

"Do people who learn music in any kind, like to show it to others? Does this make them get 
energy to become better?"

However, I'm not sure if this question can be asked here or not. If not, where can I ask such question?

If there is no other site suitable for these types of questions, then I reckon I should propose a new one.

Comment: My personal thought is "That seems out of place. This is about music, not musicians themselves", if that makes any sense. We're about the products we make as musicians, and not so much the lifestyle or energy of ourselves.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** The [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) site is now in public beta.  Please review their FAQ and ask your question there, *if appropriate!*

---

I'm going to agree with Grace here.  First let's look at our Area 51 definition:

> ## Musical Practice and Performance
>
> #### Beta Q&A site for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. Topics include practice & performance, composition, technique, theory, and history.

Obviously that puts the focus squarely on the art of creating music.  History is really the only grey area — if we allow questions about the great composers of the past, do those questions have to be related to their music?  And to what degree?

I think we've largely agreed that the focus of all questions here should be music or its production.  For example, [legal issues are off-topic](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/should-we-allow-questions-about-legal-issues).  Despite clearly being relevant to musicians and consumers of music, these questions are off-topic because the focus is on law, ehich that happens to be related to music.  The converse (music related to law) would clearly be on-topic, though I doubt there is much music written about law :P

For example, consider the generic question "Can I legally download copyrighted X without permission or payment?"  Whether X is "music" or "games" or something else, the answer doesn't really change, and it requires legal expertise — not musical expertise — to answer.  Conversely, "Will X help my guitar playing?  Why?" is about playing guitar *no matter what X is*.  Questions like that require musical expertise to answer and are what we're looking for on this site.

Now let's form the generic version of your question:

> Do people who learn X of any kind like to show it to others?

To answer this question, the knowledge you need is simply the number X-learners who like to show their skills to others (statistics).  This information would be created via a psychological study, since "well I know a few X-learners and I would say sort of" is not a good answer.  Nowhere is expertise on learning X required; no matter what X is, the question can be answered perfectly well by anyone with the information, and that person is most likely to be a statistician or a psychologist.

If you were to ask it on a statistics or psychology StackExchange site, however, I believe it would be closed for other reasons.  There appears to be no real rationale for the question beyond curiosity; SE's FAQ says questions must be about actual, practical problems.  Second, the answer to your question is "Some people sometimes".  There are a vast number of musicians in the world, with all sorts of situations and backgrounds.  Some will love performing, some will hate it; some will take the attention for granted and not improve, others will be inspired, others will retreat from it.  I'm not sure specific numbers would be any more useful.

Comment: I know more courtroom musics than you could shake a stick at!

Comment: So, @Matthew, you mean that **NOWHERE** on stack exchange network this question could be asked. Isn't it a logical bug. Because this question is a 100% valid question and you hear it being asked.

Comment: @Saeed That's not a logical bug. Simply put, not every question has a home on the Stack Exchange Network. Sometimes it's a matter of scope, other times it's just that the nature of the question conflicts with the network's initiative.

Comment: Courtroom music: http://www.sheetmusicplus.com/title/The-Iowa-Band-Law/3440109