# Legal question prohibition vs. copyright questions and the [copyright] tag: Close them all and remove the tag

Tags: discussion, tags, close-reasons, topics

There is currently a contradiction between prohibition of legal questions and the existence (and usage) of the [copyrights](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyrights) tag.

The legal questions prohibition is long established. For example

1. On our Meta since 2011, [Should we allow questions about legal issues?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/70803), which was decided in the negative;
2. Also on our Meta (2015), [Are questions on copyright on topic?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3368/70803), was answered in the negative without dissent; and
3. Our Help Center's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states "If you have a question [that] is not about business or legal issues....

**I propose that most of the copyright questions on site be closed, the others be retagged, and the [copyrights](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyrights) tag removed.**

I've found 16 "copyright questions" (list below), only one of which I think is not a legal question, and three others which might pass muster. Of the remaining 12, which IMO are "legal questions", four are closed or locked, and the rest are currently open.

I think the eight open questions should be closed, and the tag should be removed (with the understanding this is not a straightforward process, and may take a while — in the interim, the tag wiki could be updated with a "do not use" message).

---

## Copyright questions

#### The "good" question

- [How to avoid making music which already exists?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/95191/70803)

#### The borderline questions

- [Making a nursery rhyme song for kids](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/93940/70803)
- [Covering songs by other artists - does money change hands?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/764/70803)
- [Is it possible to get the actual sheet music for a particular song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/38987/70803)

#### Closed or locked copyright/legal issue questions

- [Will I have copyright problems if I use BandLab/Cakewalk?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/124497/70803)
- [What is the scope of copyright?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/118358/70803)
- [Are jazz songs in real book copyrighted? / How to check copyright of a piece?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/107070/70803)
- [Who can remix a song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/14630/70803)

#### Currently open copyright/legal issue questions

- [Can a performance of a piece be copyrighted even if the piece is public domain?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/109212/70803)
- [Are keyboard-workstation accompaniments copyrightable?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/100586/70803)
- [Do I have to pay royalties for using my own rearrangement of a famous song as videogame bgm?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/97723/70803)
- [Does including a sport commentator voice in a music track make me owe him mechanical royalties?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/96417/70803)
- [Conditions of mixage/remix of an old music track](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/75186/70803)
- [In jazz, can anyone play any song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/14303/70803)
- [When performing for money, do musicians have to buy special sheet music for copyright purposes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/57343/70803)
- [Publishing score](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/71167/70803)